# Does the improper integral of $f(x,y)=\sin(x^2+y^2)$, in all $\mathbb{R}^2$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I would like some help. If I use the Variable Change Theorem, I get that it doesn't converge, but I can't use this theorem. I made a trial using the sequence of open sets $U_n=(-n\pi,n\pi)$. Then, I make  $\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi} \sin(x^2 + y^2) dxdy $, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Break out the polar coordinates, but watch out.